# ReactJs: how to increase the count of an users as an id when fills the form from different devices or from a single device

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-forms

I made a registration form in ReactJS and **I want count of the users who were registered. when I'm trying to fill the registration form from same device the count value is increasing perfectly but when I am trying to fill the form from another device the count value is restarting**.
I tried react-redux to increase count value but there is no change.

Comment: Hi @Mamatha you are a new contributor, so its good to ask questions with code you tried,  the error you got, objective of your question and when you get answer or a hint which works for you then appreciate that. These are some community guidelines which you need to follow on SO.

Comment: In addition to Arpit's points. Please add the details about where is the data located? How are you accessing it